# How to color 56 cells in B column

Tags: excel, vba

How to write a code that colors 56 cells in B column with 56 color from color index function-> cells.interior.colorindex

Comment: Use a `For` loop

Comment: Please include what you've already attempted for this, so we can try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @niematerialny If you just want to see the 56 colors then they can be seen here http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
Sub colorCells()
     For i = 1 To 56
        Range("B1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = i
     Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I figured that was what the OP was asking for. Perhaps they wanted to see all of the colors for reference?